# Can't reference Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pex

I have VS 2010 Ultimate Edition with SP1 installed. Recently, I have noticed that I cannot refer Microsoft.Pex (v 0.94.0.0) library from my project. All my previous project are broken due to this. Every-time I try to add the reference to Pex, it says the library is incompatible with .NET 4 framework.

I even tried adding it by manually browsing to location "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll", I still get the same error.

I can't remember what caused it? Did installation of VS-SP1 broke it? I have even tried repairing the Pex installation. The problem still persist.

There is a similar post at [Can't reference Microsoft.Moles.Framework.dll in Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475441/cant-reference-microsoft-moles-framework-dll-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1), but the post did not helped either.